# Adding data to data base with variable table name

Tags: c#-4.0

in my windows form there is a comboBox that user can select name of table from that:

```
string Command = "INSERT INTO ['"+variable+"']  VALUES ('" + _ID + "','" + txt1.Text + "') ";
Connection(Command);
```

but there is an error like this
.`Could not find output table ''Tels''`

and when write `Tels` instead of `variable` it works correctly.

Comment: can you show what _Command_ has?

Comment: Google "little bobby tables"

Comment: Could it be the quotes? Remove the single quote after like [' and then before ']. So, that it would be simply like [ and ] as well.

Comment: Search for a solution where SQL injection is impossible, otherwise I will find you, and I will format your server's disk (I won't, but others will).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it myself:

```
string Command = "INSERT INTO [" + variable + "]  VALUES ('" + _ID + "','" + txt1.Text + "') ";
Connection(Command);
```

you should remove quotation mark around of variable!!!!